# mock Url.Action => returning null

Tags: c#, testing, moq

I have the following problem:

In a MVC application, Blazor, I have a controller with many methods. I am trying to test one of the methods, but after a few calls to other objects, it goes back to its controller calling a different method. This last method has the following line

```
Return Redirect(Url.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", new { id = myId }));
```

At the beginning my problem was that Url was null, however, I sorted that with the following code in my test:

```
    var UrlHelperMock = new Mock<System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper>();

    c.Url = UrlHelperMock.Object;

    UrlHelperMock.Setup(x => x.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", new { id =  MyId })).Returns("myURL" + myId.ToString());
```

Now, Url is not null anymore, but when I try to see what Url.Action returns is null instead of "myURL" + myId.ToString(). Any ideas on how to fix this, please?

Answer (score 1):

What I think is happening that the parameter `new { id = MyId }` is not equal to your setup because it is a reference type. Try doing the setup using the following code:

```cs
UrlHelperMock
    .Setup(x => x.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", It.Is<T>(y => y.id == MyId )))
    .Returns("myURL" + myId.ToString());
//where T equals the type of the parameter
```

That will check if the parameter is the type `T` and whether the id of it equals your `MyId`.

Comment: T as generic errors

Comment: @Iria I placed it as placeholder because your question doesn't specify what type of class you use as parameter. If it's for example `new Person { id = MyId }` then use `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

what it sorted for me was realizing that id needs to be just anything, so doing instead:

```
UrlHelperMock.Setup(x => x.Action("MyActionName", "MyControllerName", It.IsAny<object>() })).Returns("myURL" + myId.ToString());
```

Giving it as a gener T was erroring as it needed to be specific, and string didn't work either because there is no string.id, same for other types.